# PThreads: Cores vs Threads

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

I'm using a complex C code that has parallel support through posix threads. It was written before hyperthreading existed.

I am running the code on a Macbook i5 (2 Cores 4 Threads). Since the code has various malloc errors and such when forcing to run on 4 threads, but is fine on 2 threads it has made me question: **Do you require specialist programming to enable parallel pthreaded code to support hyperthreading?**

Since I know absolutely nothing about pthreads, I assumed that it would automatically detect the number of threads available and run fine, rather than only run correctly with the number of physical cores.

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't need special support in your userland code. The OS hides all the differences for you.

If your code isn't running properly when you increase your thread count, you've got a bug.